# Тесты NUnit не запускаются на netstandard2.1

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-standard

У меня есть новый проект, создавал по гайду<sup>[1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit)</sup>: решение и в нём два проекта: `MathUtilities` и `MathUtilities.Tests`; всё через консоль, установлен .NET Core 3.0 (Ubuntu 19.10).

Я пробовал уже ставить вместо `netstandard2.1` версию `2.0`, но всё равно появляется ошибка `Не удалось найти ~/math-utilities/MathUtilities.Tests/bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/testhost.dll. Опубликуйте тестовый проект и повторите попытку`. Пробовал добавлять `NUnit3TestAdapter` версии `3.15.1`, но тоже ничего не происходит. Почему так происходит? Неужели NUnit не совместим совсем с netstandard2.{0,1}?

Я вижу, что в получившихся исходниках по гайду указана платформа `netcoreapp3.0` для тестового проекта, разве `netstandard2.1` не совместим?

Листинг `MathUtilities.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Листинг `MathUtilities.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MathUtilities\MathUtilities.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Листинг кода:

```
namespace MathUtilities
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public bool t() =>
            true;
    }
}
```

Листинг теста:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MathUtilities.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        private Class1 class1;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            class1 = new Class1();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(class1.t());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а где сами тесты и как вы их запускали?

Comment: @tym32167 вообще не работает никак, но добавил то, что есть сейчас

Comment: вот [это](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard) смотрели?

Comment: вы добавили тесты, но не указали, как вы их запускали

Comment: @tym32167 я запускал их через `dotnet test MathUtilities.Tests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ очень прост: тесты NUnit совсем не поддерживают тип проекта `netstandard2.1`, вместо этого `netcoreapp3.1`. К сожалению, я пропустил это, когда читал гайд [.NET Core and .NET Standard](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard#why-cant-my-tests-target-net-standard), где написано, что проект тестов не может быть `netstandard` по некоторым причинам, но можно использовать совместимый `netcoreapp3.1`.